# Why does AdaBoost or GradientBoosting ensemble with a single estimator give different values than the single estimator?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, ensemble-learning, adaboost

I'm curious why a single-estimator Adaboost "ensemble", a single-estimator Gradient Boosted "ensemble" and a single decision tree give different values.

The code below compares three models, all using the same base estimator (regression tree with max_depth = 4 and loss based on mse.)

1. The base estimate as a bare tree model
2. A single-estimator Adaboost using the base estimator as a prototype
3. A single-estimator GBR using the base estimator as a prototype

Extracting and inspecting the trees indicate they are very different, even though each should have been trained in the same fashion.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostRegressor, GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor, export_text

data = load_diabetes()
X = data['data']
y = data['target']

simple_model = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=4)
prototype = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=4)
simple_ada = AdaBoostRegressor(prototype, n_estimators=1)
simple_gbr = GradientBoostingRegressor(max_depth=4, n_estimators=1, criterion='mse')

simple_model.fit(X, y)
simple_ada.fit(X, y)
simple_gbr.fit(X, y)

ada_one = simple_ada.estimators_[0]
gbr_one = simple_gbr.estimators_[0][0]

print(export_text(simple_model))
print(export_text(ada_one))
print(export_text(gbr_one))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AdaBoostRegressor` performs weighted bootstrap sampling for each of its trees (unlike `AdaBoostClassifier` which IIRC just fits the base classifier using sample weights):  [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/32f9deaaf27c7ae56898222be9d820ba0fd1054f/sklearn/ensemble/_weight_boosting.py#L1140-L1146).  So there's no way to enforce that a single-tree AdaBoost regressor matches a single decision tree (without, I suppose, doing the bootstrap sampling manually and fitting the single decision tree).

---

`GradientBoostingRegressor` has an initial value for each sample to boost from:

> **init : *estimator or ‘zero’, default=None***
> An estimator object that is used to compute the initial predictions. `init` has to provide fit and predict. If ‘zero’, the initial raw predictions are set to zero. By default a `DummyEstimator` is used, predicting either the average target value (for loss=’squared_error’), or a quantile for the other losses.

So the main difference between your tree and single-estimator-gbm is that the latter's leaf values are shifted by the average target value.  Setting `init='zero'` gets us much closer, but I do see some differences in chosen splits further down the tree.  *That* is due to ties in optimal split values, and can be fixed by setting a common `random_state` throughout.